# Countable many flat regions in a cdf?

Tags: real-analysis

Consider a continuous cumulative distribution function with bounded support [a,b].

Can the number of flat regions of this cdf be uncountable?

Since each flat region must have a positive measure, i.e, there must be an interval in which the cdf is flat, it seems that if there were uncountably many flat regions, than the measure of the flat regions would be grater than the interval (a,b)

Is my intuition correct? Can anyone point me to a formal proof?

Comment: Each flat region contains a rational, and there are only countably many of those.

Answer (score 0):

Let $f$ be a cumulative distribution function.

Given $\epsilon > 0$, there are a finite number of flat regions greater than $\epsilon$, otherwise the support of $f$ would be unbouded.

Therefore there are countably many flat regions.

You can count the flat regions by counting the flat regions greater than $\frac{1}{n}$ for every $n \geq 1$.